# .htaccess from ModX to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, modx

Working on a project that requires a migration from ModX to WordPress.

The URL will need to change as follows:

```
•         Currently (ModX):   http://www.acme.com/finance-about
•         Migrating to (WordPress):  http://www.acme.com/finance/finance-about/
```

Or we have some sites that might look like this

```
•         Currently (ModX):  http://www.acme.com/risk-management-about
•         Migrating to (WordPress):  http://www.acme.com/risk-management/risk-management-about/
```

What I have tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/WPassets/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)-([a-zA-Z_-]+)$ $1-$2/ [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ $1/ [L]
```

Comment: The only thing those rules appear to do is add a trailing slash

Answer (score 1):

Place this rule just below `RewriteBase` line in your `wordpress .htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/-]+)/?$ /$1/$0 [L,R=301]
```

This will perform following redirections with `R=301`

- `/finance-about` to `/finance/finance-about`
- `/anything-here` to `/anything/anything-here`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)-about$ /$1/$1-about/
```

Or:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-about$ /$1/$1-about/ [L,R=301]
```